# Какова функция языка в данном сообщении? (3)

Tags: недопустимая-метка

"Не жалею! Не зову! Не плачу! Все пройдет, как с белых яблонь дым..."

Comment: Почему Вы изменили пунктуацию в стихотворении Есенина?

Answer (score 2):

Это также коммуникативная функция, но в ее пределах можно выделить **эмоциональную и эстетическую функции**, которые связаны с художественной литературой.

О функциях языка: http://fb.ru/article/44622/osnovnyie-funktsii-yazyika

**Художественная литература**  выполняет образно-познавательную и идейно-эстетическую функцию.

Основные функции художественной литературы. https://studfiles.net/preview/6359586/page:2/